# Cocos2d Javascript .Apk Crashes on Startup

Tags: javascript, android, cocos2d-android, cocos2d-js

I made a Cocos2d-js 3.5 project using the "Empty Complete Project" template in Cocos. It runs fine on Android when I debug from Cocos Code, but when I compile an .apk with "cocos compile -p android -m debug", copy it to my Galaxy S4 running Cyanogenmod 11 and install it, it crashes on startup with no useful error messages. All it gives me is a popup that says "Unfortunately [my app] has died". Similarly, the only relevant message I can find with Logcat "[my app] has stopped". I've recreated the project and tried it in release mode and with NDKs r10c, r10d, and now r9d, and it's always the same. This is really frustrating. Any ideas?

EDIT: Update: tested on 2 friends' phones, same error.

EDIT AGAIN: I set up the exact same environment on my old Macbook, and it works great. (Previously I was on Windows 7.) I guess that will have to do.